# Textbox with textmode time, won't display data from sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So i did a research about textmode time but it doesn't seem to help me. My problem is when i tried to bind the data with time textmode it won't display anything I already tried removing the textmode so i can see if it can display data and it does. Here's my code in the front, hope you'll help me. Thank you in advance

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrTRFFormItems" OnItemDataBound="rptrTRFFormItems_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="No" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>' Visible="false">
        </asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAddItemRow" CssClass="actionbtnstyle fa fa-plus-square" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAddItemRows" Style="font-size: 20px;">
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDeleteItemRow" CssClass="actionbtnstyle fa fa-minus-square" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnDeleteItemRows" Style="font-size: 20px;">
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div runat="server" id="divInputGroup">
          <span runat="server" id="spanInputGroup">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="validatetbName">
            </asp:Label>
          </span>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbName" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' CssClass="form-control rptrtbstyle" ondrop="return false" title="Required" data-toggle="tooltip" TabIndex="13" data-placement="bottom">
          </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="rptriddate" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbDate" EventName="TextChanged" />
          </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="divInputGroup0">
              <span runat="server" id="spanInputGroup0">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="validatetbDate">
                </asp:Label>
              </span>
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbDate" CssClass="form-control js-datepicker rptrtbstyle" Style="cursor: pointer;" TabIndex="14" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Required" OnTextChanged="tbDate_TextChanged" autocomplete="off" AutoPostBack="true">
              </asp:TextBox>
            </div>
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div runat="server" id="divInputGroup2">
          <span runat="server" id="spanInputGroup2">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="validatetbPreferredTime">
            </asp:Label>
          </span>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPreferredTime" Text='<%#Eval("PreferredTime") %>' format="HH:mm" TextMode="Time"  CssClass="form-control rptrtbstyle" data-toggle="tooltip" TabIndex="15" data-placement="bottom" title="Required">
          </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div runat="server" id="divInputGroup1">
          <span runat="server" id="spanInputGroup1">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="validatetbFromRptr">
            </asp:Label>
          </span>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFromRptr" Text='<%#Eval("FromRptr") %>' CssClass="form-control rptrtbstyle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" TabIndex="16" title="Required" AutoPostBack="false">
          </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnExchange" CssClass="actionbtnstyle fa fa-exchange" CausesValidation="false" Style="font-size: 20px;">
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div runat="server" id="divInputGroup3">
          <span runat="server" id="spanInputGroup3">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="validatetbToRptr">
            </asp:Label>
          </span>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbToRptr"  Text='<%#Eval("ToRptr") %>' CssClass="form-control rptrtbstyle" TabIndex="17" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Required">
          </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <%--</ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And here's the code to bind data from behind.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(travelrequest))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "TRFSearchByRefernce";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trfNo", txtSearchByReference.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", lblFullname01.Text);
        using(SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rptrTRFFormItems.DataSource = dt;
                rptrTRFFormItems.DataBind();
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            }
            else
            {
                SetInitialRow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my stored procedure sql query

```
SELECT  
[TRFGName] as Name
,[TRFGDate] as [Date]
,[TRFGTimeRef] as PreferredTime
,[TRFGFrom] as FromRptr
,[TRFGTo] as ToRptr
,[TRFGNo]
,[TRFGControlNo]
,[TRFRequester]

FROM [TRAVELREQUESTFORM].[TRAVEL].[TRAVELGRID]  WHERE TRFGControlNo = @trfNo and TRFRequester = @fullname
```

Comment: Yea I think the issue is you're not understanding the use of Eval().  It can only be used within a databinding context, meaning your asp:TextBox has to be within a repeater.  If this is the case can you edit your post and include the markup around the textbox involved in databinding.   If you don't understand what I'm saying I'd suggest having a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder.eval?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It is inside the repeater actually. I'll edit it anyway :). btw all other data bindings works perfectly fine inside the repeater expect the time textmode.

Comment: This article might be of assistance... 

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/776764/Introducing-Textmode-in-ASP-NET

It says it's not supported in IE.  Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: I'm currently using google chrome sir.

Comment: Whats the type of the TRFGTimeRef column?

Comment: And what's a sample of the value for this column? Basically Eval("PreferredTime") needs to resolve to a string that looks like HH:MM:SS e.g. 06:43:21

Comment: I've solved it!! Thanks for the idea sir. Actually the issue is that the textmode time is needed to be at the same format as the one that i'm inserting to my database. Unfortunately i'm inserting a different format and using an 'nvarchar' as datatype so, I tried to convert the column in my query like this (Convert(time,TRFGTimeRef)) as PreferredTime and it works perfectly fine. Thankyouuuuuuuu!! I've been solving this for 2 days in a row now. Great!!!